# How to update using SQLAlchemy and session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When I want to add a row to my MyProducts table I do:

```
p = models.MyProducts(code="123456")
db.session.add(p)
db.session.commit()
```

Inside `models.py` I have:

```
class MyProducts(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True)
    code = db.Column(db.Integer)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(99999), default="")
    pricepaid = db.Column(db.Float(264), default="0.0")
```

How do I go about updating my the row that has a code of "123456" ?
I have tried

```
updater = models.MyProducts.query.filter_by(code="123456").update({'comment':"greeeeat product"})
db.session.add(updater)
db.session.commit()
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming it is just one product:

```
my_product = models.MyProducts.query.filter_by(code=123456).first()  # @note: code is Integer, not a String, right?
if my_product:
    my_product.comment = "greeeeat product"
    db.session.add(my_product)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I guess I'm confused about how add() works. How does it know to update the row and not just add a new one?